# Texture atlasing in blender to substance painter?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, uv-image-editor, development

I am working on many assets for a game proyect , I used blender to model the props and prefer substance to work on pbr shader for unity engine 5.5 , first of all , before ask my question , I need to introduce you to my workflow (check it in pictures above) :

[image]

so In the picture up there , you see the props with respective ID map , all of them in the one UV space called  "texture atlas"  ( remember when you pressed "start manual unwrap" in Texture atlas , it creates an ONLY ONE OBJECT called "TextureAtlas_MergedObject" ).

then , I check all the name of the materials from the mesh of every objects , as in this picture (texture atlas make the ability to create all the objects in provisory single mesh object) .

[image]

so nothing extraordinary at the moment , the thigs will change in substance painter , so I need a help (consider this is not a modular design  , where there are structures as wall and you can Uv's them with 90 degree , this is more difficult , cause angles , shapes )

so...before to introduce you to my  problems check this in substance :

[image]

so at simple view, everything seems to match , every "main shader" search the information of the texture atlas uv space , consider that it was ONLY ONLY ONE object (merged, cause when I create the texture atlas , every objects joins in only one objects...so the exported one , it is only one object! then I will or I prefer to separate this object)

well continue with this thread , when I export all the texture , the desired texture I ve been created in substance , the folder shows me every piece of meshes, but not the atlas , look at this ;

[image]

so in the picture above , the pixel that are Furthermore the UV space , there are NUll values , not exist as iteration of the objects in real time , they exist as pixels but when 3D models are created as objects in Unity or whatever, the UV just recognised the limit of the uv , might be some bleeding space to avoid seams ... I think substance always create a blur extened pixels furthermore the uv space...so my doubt here is I would like to keep the Texture atlas not portions of it, I ve noticed I ve only see in my export folder, just portion of the atlas.

check this ... I think the most powerful thing the texture atlas can make or handle is the way of put many objects in uv space, but substance painter not showme the others object in my texture atlas, just use their uv coordinates and create me individual portions of the uv ... I hope you can help me . [image]

consider this is a texture atlas , every uv's are in the same space, a head a piece of spoon , a tomato , and stuff,  (the last picture), I ve painted it on texture paint blender internal , but blender internal not support pbr, but the texture atlas's painting is useful as this :

[image]